# In SQL I would like to subtract a date from a previous row date

Tags: c#, sql

The problem is that the dates are stored in the SQL database as `nvarchar()` and the times are stored in a separate column. I only have read access to this database, so I can't change the format. Besides, it would probably void our support if the manufacturer found out.

As I see I need to first combine the dates and times into one cell as a datetime and then subtract the previous row from the current.

```
ActualTime, ActualDate
5:30:26,    31-Dec-09
16:01:47,   31-Dec-09
17:35:50,   31-Dec-09
18:31:31,   31-Dec-09
18:51:03,   31-Dec-09
18:55:35,   31-Dec-09
19:26:53,   31-Dec-09
 5:25:37,   1-Jan-10
5:38:36,    1-Jan-10
5:46:58,    1-Jan-10
6:27:00,    1-Jan-10
```

Several people have asked what language I was using. I was hoping to do all of this at the server. On the code side (C#) it's a trivial problem.
Like I said I am looking for an SQL Server server-side solution.

Comment: are you trying to find the time difference between two rows ?

Comment: yes, but keep in mind that the datatypes are varchar

Comment: i think i have covered just about every case now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Microsoft SQL Server, to convert your columns in a date you can

```
Select Cast( ActualDate + ' ' + ActualTime AS DateTime)
```

to compare between two dates

```
Select
    Datediff(
             second,
             Cast('13-dec-2009 ' + '19:39:33' As DateTime),
             Cast('13-dec-2009 ' + '19:26:33' As DateTime)
            )
```

More on *[DATEDIFF (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)* parameters.

And to get the difference from the current date/time use the [`GETDATE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx),

```
    Select
       *,
       oldness = DateDiff(
                   second,
                   GETDATE(),
                   Cast(ActualDate + ' ' + ActualTime AS DateTime)
                  )
    From
       your_table
```

Finally to do it between rows (for the whole table..),

```
Select  *,
        Cast(ActualDate + ' ' + ActualTime AS DateTime) as [fulldate],
        DiffFromPrevious = Coalesce(
            DateDiff(
                second,
                (
                  Select Top 1 Cast(ActualDate + ' ' + ActualTime AS DateTime) AS [fulldate]
                  From yourtable
                  Where Cast(ActualDate + ' ' + ActualTime AS DateTime) < Cast(t1.ActualDate + ' ' + t1.ActualTime AS DateTime)
                  Order By [fulldate] Desc
                ),
                Cast(ActualDate + ' ' + ActualTime AS DateTime)
            ),
        0)
From
    yourtable t1
Order By
    [fulldate] Asc
```

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using, and what kind of Database is it? I'm not sure if the database has capabilities to do row manipulation within a query (subtracting one row from the other), so you would have to do this programmatically. I'm not sure what language you're using, but if it has a `Date` or `Time` API then you can use that to create a `Date` object. There should a function that returns the total number of seconds since a starting date (January 1, 1970 or something). You create your two `Date` objects, convert into number of seconds and then subtract them. You can then calculate the number of days between them.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using PHP, I suggest you use the strtotime() function to convert it into a time object. Do this for both dates. The difference will give you the number of seconds between them.

Comment: The OP asked for an `SQL` solution.